# Stripe.js - Collecting recipient information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stripe-payments

Stripe now offers payouts, which work by creating a **bank account token** on the front end. From there, the token is send to the server where you create a **recipient** object with that bank account token. From there you use this recipient object in transfers.

While I am familiar you can create [custom forms for payments](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) with *stripe.js*, when it comes to creating a token for recipients, I can't seem to find any documentation other than [this](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-bank-account-details).

Here is my problem, first my form:

```
<form method="POST" id="inst-form">    

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Bank Location</span>
            <select data-stripe="country">
                <option value="US">United States</option>
            </select>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Routing Number</span>
            <input type="text" size="9" data-stripe="routingNumber"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Account Number</span>
            <input type="text" size="17" data-stripe="accountNumber"/>
      </label>
    </div>


    <button type="submit">Make Recipient!</button>
</form>
```

So far, the three things I need from this form are **country, routingNumber, and accountNumber**. Lets look at the Javascript so I can use those fields with Stripe.js:

```
  // Create a handler to manage what Stripe returns.
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#inst-form');
    if (response.error)
    {
      alert("Error");
      // Not sure how to get these errors.
      $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
      var token = response.id;
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
      $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // Now the handler is done, lets use it when the form is submitted.
  // On form submission execute:
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#inst-form').submit(function(event) {
      // Get the form object.
      var $form = $(this);
      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
      // Create a token with Stripe
      Stripe.bankAccount.createToken({
        country: $('.country').val(),
        routingNumber: $('.routingNumber').val(),
        accountNumber: $('.accountNumber').val(),
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
```

My problem is that the **alert()** is being triggered, which means there are errors. I looked through the API and I am not sure on how to display those errors specifically for creating a recipient. For payments it gives the following example:

```
$(".payment-errors").text(response.error.message);
```

Note - I excluded the import of jQuery/Stripe.js - that is surely not the problem.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

My experience has been that response.error.message is indeed the correct way to proceed.

Here is a sample of my own code for this:

```
Stripe.bankAccount.createToken({
    country: 'US',
    routingNumber: bank_routing_number,
    accountNumber: bank_account_number,
}, function(status, response) {
    if (response.error)
    {
        console.log(response);
        alert(response.error.message);
    }
    else
    {
        var token = response.id;
        /* send the token to the server along with the withdraw request */
    }
});
```

If you still aren't seeing the correct errors, you should try to console.log(response) and view the javascript console for clues.

Here is an example of an easy error to reproduce:

> Routing number must have 9 digits

You should, of course, be validating your account and routing numbers with the routines that Stripe.js provides. Here example usage taken from their documentation:

```
// This will return true, indicating a potentially valid bank
// routing number.

Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber('111000025')
Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber('110000000')

// These invalid bank routing numbers will all return false.

Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber('990000000')
// (Doesn't pass the checksum check.)
Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber('12345')
Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber('mistake')
```

The docs for this are here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-bank-account-details

Answer (score 0):

Just change your form as below. other things are fine.
Because you are fetching value as **$('.country').val()** where **.country** indicate there should be class. so just add class in your form just like below.

```
<form method="POST" id="inst-form">    

<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Bank Location</span>
        <select data-stripe="country" class="country">
            <option value="US">United States</option>
        </select>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Routing Number</span>
        <input type="text" size="9" data-stripe="routingNumber" class="routingNumber"/>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Account Number</span>
        <input type="text" size="17" data-stripe="accountNumber" class="accountNumber"/>
  </label>
</div>

<button type="submit">Make Recipient!</button>
```